# Need to find the tags under a tag in an XML using jQuery

Tags: jquery-selectors

I have this xml as part of the responseXml of an Ajax call:

```
<banner-ad>
    <title><span style="color:#ffff00;"><strong>Title</strong></span></title>
</banner-ad>
```

When I used this jQuery(responseXml).find("title").text(); the result is "Title".
I also tried jQuery(responseXml).find("title:first-child") but the result is [object Object].

I want to get the result:

```
<span style="color:#ffff00;"><strong>Title</strong></span>
```

Please let me know how to do this in jQuery.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Regards,
Racs

Comment: Is there any chance for you to influence the XML itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you cannot simply append nodes from one document (the XML response) to another (your HTML page). The issue is two-fold:

1. You can use jQuery to append nodes from the XML document to the HTML page. This works; the nodes appear in the HTML DOM, but they stay XML nodes and therefore the browser ignores the `style` attribute, for example. Consequently the text will not be yellow (`#ffff00`).
2. As far as I can see, jQuery offers no built-in way to get the XML string (i.e. a *serialized* node) from an XML node. jQuery can handle XML documents quite well, but there is no equivalent to what `.html()` does in HTML documents.

So to make this work we need to extract the XML string from the XML document. Some browsers support the `.xml` property on XML nodes (namely, IE), the others come with an `XMLSerializer` object:

```
// find the proper XML node
var $title = $(doc).find("title");

// either use .xml or, when unavailable, an XMLSerializer 
var html = $title[0].xml || (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString($title[0]);

// result:
// '<title><span style="color:#ffff00;"><strong>Title</strong></span></title>'
```

Then we have to feed this HTML string to jQuery so new, real HTML elements can be created from it:

```
$("#target").append(html);
```

There is a fiddle to show this in action: http://jsfiddle.net/Tomalak/QWHj8/. This example also gets rid of the superfluous `<title>` element.

---

Anyway. If you have a chance to influence the XML itself, it would make sense to change it:

```
<banner-ad>
    <title>&lt;span style="color:#ffff00;"&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Title&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/span&gt;</title>
</banner-ad>
```

Just XML-encode the payload of `<title>` and you can do this in jQuery:

```
$("#target").append( $(doc).find("title").text() );
```

Comment: Hi Tomalak, thanks for this. I tried your first suggestion (use $title[0].xml || (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString($title[0])) but it did not work. However, your second suggestion works. :-) To influence the xml itself, I go to the servlet that gets the result from database then set response.setContentType("text/html"). Also, I used StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml(title) to achieve this result: <title>&lt;span style="color:#ffff00;"&gt;&lt; Then I go to my javascript and set also the dataType: 'html'. Finally, I used jQuery(responseXml).find("title").text() and got what I need. Thanks again!

Comment: By the way, I found the escaping util from Oleg here's the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5008282/954203)

Comment: @Racs Nice to hear you got the second suggestion working. Can you be a little more specific about what didn't work with the first suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

This would probably work:

```
$(responseXml).find("title").html();
```

Comment: Hi Bogdan, thanks for this. I tried it also but the result appended to my target is this "<span style="color:#fffff00;">". It seems that it is translating the code literally.. I used Tomalak's second suggestion above after setting the Content Type of my servlet from "text/xml" to "text/html".